# I am not able to set a cookie in php

Tags: php

```
  <?php
  $product1 = "user";


  if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
  $value=1;
  echo "Cookie named '" . $product1 . "' is not set!";
   setcookie($product1, $value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
   } else {
  echo "Cookie '" . $product1 . "' is set!<br>";
  echo "Value is: " . $_COOKIE[$product1];
   $value=$_COOKIE[$product1];
   setcookie($product1, $value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
   }
   ?>
```

// i keep getting the message cookie named user is not set even after refreshing the page. Please help

Comment: i changed $cookie_name to $product in the if statement

Answer (score 0):

```
  $product1 = "user";
//print_r($_COOKIE);

  if(!isset($_COOKIE[$product1])) {
  $value=1;
  echo "Cookie named '" . $product1 . "' is not set!";
   setcookie($product1, $value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
   } else {
  echo "Cookie '" . $product1 . "' is set!<br>";
  echo "Value is: " . $_COOKIE[$product1];
   $value=$_COOKIE[$product1];
   setcookie($product1, $value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
   }
```

Comment: it worked but what is the difference? except the problem in if condition